# How to copy "GitHub Project Display Widget" in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am basically trying to create the following (an image from GitHub):

[image]

Notice that this widget is composed of two halves. I am having a lot of difficulty trying to re-create this type of widget. I am able to create individual halves but attempting to display both in the same fashion becomes distorted. Below is one attempt,

```
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <h3>Text here!</h3>
          <p style="color:rgb(233,233,233);font-style: italic;">Some Text!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Comment: Have your tried using ctrl + shift + c and then clicking on this element in Github? You could copy parts of their code that they have used to create this affect.

Comment: Yeah I did, and I was having a lot of difficulty. I simply couldn't replicate it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a similar looking example:

```css
*{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font: 13px/1.4 Helvetica, arial, freesans, clean, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

div {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width:225px;
}

h3 {
    width: 225px;
    height: 102px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top:40px;
    background-image : url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNDQiIGhlaWdodD0iMTQ0Ij48cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMTAwJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAlIiBmaWxsPSJyZ2IoMTg1LCAxNDIsIDc1KSIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9IjEyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzIyMiIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wNDY7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9IjEyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjEyNDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAxIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNi4wIiBjeT0iMTIuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZGRkIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjAzNzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjM2LjAiIGN5PSIxMi4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiMyMjIiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wNDYiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjYwLjAiIGN5PSIxMi4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDM3MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzM7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNjAuMCIgY3k9IjEyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA3MjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAxIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI4NC4wIiBjeT0iMTIuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMjIyIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjEzMjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY1O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9Ijg0LjAiIGN5PSIxMi4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wMiIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTA4LjAiIGN5PSIxMi4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDI4NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEwOC4wIiBjeT0iMTIuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMDQ2IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMzIuMCIgY3k9IjEyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzIyMiIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wNDY7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTMyLjAiIGN5PSIxMi4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiMyMjIiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wNjMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNCIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9IjM2LjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4xMDY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMi4wIiBjeT0iMzYuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMTE1MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjM2LjAiIGN5PSIzNi4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDM3MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzM7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMzYuMCIgY3k9IjM2LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA4OTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2MC4wIiBjeT0iMzYuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZGRkIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjA4OTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjYwLjAiIGN5PSIzNi4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wNTQ2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iODQuMCIgY3k9IjM2LjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzIyMiIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4xNTtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI4NC4wIiBjeT0iMzYuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjZGRkIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMDM3MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEwOC4wIiBjeT0iMzYuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMjIyIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjEzMjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY1O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEwOC4wIiBjeT0iMzYuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMDI4NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMzIuMCIgY3k9IjM2LjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wNzIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMTtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMzIuMCIgY3k9IjM2LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjAyIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMi4wIiBjeT0iNjAuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZGRkIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjA4OTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEyLjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiMyMjIiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xMTUzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNCIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMzYuMCIgY3k9IjYwLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wODkzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNi4wIiBjeT0iNjAuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjZGRkIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMTQxMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjYwLjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTQxMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNjAuMCIgY3k9IjYwLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA4OTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI4NC4wIiBjeT0iNjAuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZGRkIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjA3MjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAxO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9Ijg0LjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xMjQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMSIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTA4LjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTI0MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDE7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTA4LjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiMyMjIiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xMTUzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNCIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTMyLjAiIGN5PSI2MC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDk4O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEzMi4wIiBjeT0iNjAuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjZGRkIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMDU0NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjciICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEyLjAiIGN5PSI4NC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTU7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9Ijg0LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjE0MTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzM0IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNi4wIiBjeT0iODQuMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjMjIyIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjE1O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjM2LjAiIGN5PSI4NC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xMDY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNjAuMCIgY3k9Ijg0LjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4xMDY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2MC4wIiBjeT0iODQuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMTUiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9Ijg0LjAiIGN5PSI4NC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTQxMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iODQuMCIgY3k9Ijg0LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iIzIyMiIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjE1IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMDguMCIgY3k9Ijg0LjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wNTQ2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMDguMCIgY3k9Ijg0LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iIzIyMiIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA5OCIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTMyLjAiIGN5PSI4NC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTE1MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTMyLjAiIGN5PSI4NC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xMjQwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMSIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTI0MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDE7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTIuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wNzIwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMSIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMzYuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDg5MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzM7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMzYuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4xNDEzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNCIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNjAuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiNkZGQiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTQxMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iNjAuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wODkzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iODQuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMTE1MzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iODQuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSI1LjAiIGZpbGw9IiNkZGQiIGZpbGwtb3BhY2l0eT0iMC4wODkzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTA4LjAiIGN5PSIxMDguMCIgcj0iMTAuMCIgZmlsbD0ibm9uZSIgc3Ryb2tlPSIjZGRkIiBzdHlsZT0ib3BhY2l0eTowLjAyO3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEwOC4wIiBjeT0iMTA4LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA3MjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAxIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMzIuMCIgY3k9IjEwOC4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDI4NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEzMi4wIiBjeT0iMTA4LjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iIzIyMiIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjEzMjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY1IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMi4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wMzczMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMi4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iIzIyMiIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjE1IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNi4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wNTQ2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzNi4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjA4OTMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2MC4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iI2RkZCIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4wODkzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMztzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI2MC4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjAzNzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzIiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI4NC4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjEwLjAiIGZpbGw9Im5vbmUiIHN0cm9rZT0iIzIyMiIgc3R5bGU9Im9wYWNpdHk6MC4xMTUzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzNDtzdHJva2Utd2lkdGg6NC4wcHg7IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSI4NC4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iI2RkZCIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjEwNjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY3IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMDguMCIgY3k9IjEzMi4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDYzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzQ7c3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoOjQuMHB4OyIgIC8+PGNpcmNsZSBjeD0iMTA4LjAiIGN5PSIxMzIuMCIgcj0iNS4wIiBmaWxsPSIjMjIyIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMDQ2IiAgLz48Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMzIuMCIgY3k9IjEzMi4wIiByPSIxMC4wIiBmaWxsPSJub25lIiBzdHJva2U9IiMyMjIiIHN0eWxlPSJvcGFjaXR5OjAuMDQ2O3N0cm9rZS13aWR0aDo0LjBweDsiICAvPjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEzMi4wIiBjeT0iMTMyLjAiIHI9IjUuMCIgZmlsbD0iIzIyMiIgZmlsbC1vcGFjaXR5PSIwLjAyODY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NjY2NyIgIC8+PC9zdmc+);
}

p {
    width:223px;
    padding:20px;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h3>DevOps tools</h3> 
    <p>These tools help you manage servers and deploy happier and more often with more confidence.</p>
</div>
```